# How to access assembly language symbols without a leading _ from C on 6502 (cc65)

Tags: c, assembly, abi, name-mangling, 6502

I'm writing some code in 6502 assembly language using cc65.

Because I'm living in 2022 and not 1979 and have access to a development machine that is a million times more powerful than the target platform, I'm writing unit tests for the assembly language code in C.

Obviously the calling conventions for C and assembly language are different, so I have a bunch of wrapper functions that accept C-style arguments and then call the assembly language functions.

But after calling an assembly language function, I want to check the state of various globals that are defined in assembly language, but I can't because C expects all identifiers to start with an underscore `'_'` and the identifiers in my assembly language modules don't.

I could just export every symbol twice, once with a `'_'` prefix and once without, but it seems so clunky and I just wonder if there's an easier way? Is there a `#pragma` or something that I can use to tell C to use the symbol name exactly as-is, without adding an underscore?

I've looked in the cc65 docs and found nothing, but it seems like a pretty common need, and I'm wondering what other people do.

Comment: The normal solution is to use names that start with an underscore for symbols that should be accessible from C.

Comment: I realize that; I'm asking if there's a way that doesn't involve using C names throughout an assembly language project.

Comment: Well you can make aliases with an `EQU` directive.  But apart from that, I don't think there's a solution.  The compiler clearly does not support accessing symbols other than those starting with an underscore.

Comment: Oh could I just create those mappings in the file with the C wrapper functions then? I just want to keep them out of the main assembly language modules.

Comment: Sure, I think it should just work.

Comment: @fuz: If the C compiler supports GNU extensions, `extern int foo  asm("bar");` will make it use the asm symbol name `bar` for that global, overriding any name mangling or decoration.  So you could use it like `extern int foo asm("foo")` to get `foo` instead of `_foo`.  You could wrap that in a CPP macro to declare a name and stringify it.  But if that's not supported, then yeah making aliases in one asm file is probably good, either symbol aliases or with an asm preprocessor.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately looks like cc65 doesn't support the use of `asm` in the extern declaration though.

Comment: @fuz If you create an answer with your suggestion to just use `EQU` in the wrapper function module then I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the cc65 compiler only supports access to symbols with the ABI-specificed decoration, i.e. those beginning in an underscore `_`.

To access other symbols, they therefore must either be renamed to follow the decoration or a decorated alias must be created.

```
_foo    EQU foo
```

For functions, it is also worth considering to write wrapper functions.  This may improve the ability to debug the code as debuggers tend to get confused when two symbols refer to the same address.